# Persisting data between app launches

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I have small set of data to be persisted between different app launches... This data is the versions of some files which I will be checking on my app launch. I am planning to maintain a dictionary with key a file name and value as version of the file.

What is the best possible option to persist this data. I could think of using NSUserDefaults for this.

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults should work fine. If you need a reference see: http://www.tomwhitson.co.uk/blog/tag/persistent-data/.

Comment: Ok Kevin. One question. Does it mean that these values are only for the current logged in user. Let's say if a different user logs in the application in the same device, will he be able to see the persisted data which was saved when user 1 was logged in the same device?

Comment: As far as I am aware it is impossible to have multiple users on a non broken iOS device.